# Unable to see and edit the character that is typed when you press the Enter key in simple text editors like KWrite

Tags: kde, text-processing, text-editor

I'm a newbie to the KDE Plasma interface. I find myself unable to see and edit the character that is typed when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in simple text editors like KWrite.

Comment: What do you mean by "line shift"? Do you mean LF (`^J`, `012`, `0x0A`)? Linux/Unix uses LF as an End-of-Line indicator. I'm unfamiliar with KWrite, but does it offer a command to "join" lines? That would have the effect of deleting s LF.

Comment: I'm not sure of its official name, but if you hit the enter bottom while writing text you get a line-shift.

To remove this I used to search and replace them in a simple writer program, but now on KDE, I cant see these line-shifts, and therefor not search and replace them.

it doesn't have to be KWriter, just any Ubuntu text editor......

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're asking "is there a text editor for KDE that shows line-feeds/carriage returns (LF/CR)"? Kate (which you probably have installed) can show some whitespace characters, or Notepad++, VS Code, jEdit, ...

Comment: Have you tried searching and replacing the new line character `\n`? I believe this works on gedit using the find and replace feature but it does not show a character for a new line (you cannot see the new line characters, `\n` on the text editor but you can enter `\n` into the find field for find and replace and it will find the new lines and replace them with whatever).

Comment: We can reopen this if you help to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mousepad, a simple text editor for the Xfce Desktop Environment, is maybe the simplest way to reduce/increase the amounts of paragraph characters, as copy & paste is possible if "Display line endings" is selected!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The linefeed in Gedit text editor and many other text editors such as Emacs and KWrite is denoted by the `\n` regular expression. The below screenshot shows the how to use `\n` in Gedit text editor. The Find and Replace feature in Gedit is accessed by ≡ (Gedit options) → *Find and Replace*. Check the regular expression checkbox so that `\n` will be recognized as a regular expression instead of as two separate characters.

[image]
<sup>**Regular expression mode in Gedit Find and Replace**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Regular expression mode in KWrite text editor**</sup>

In LibreOffice Writer a new paragraph character is typed in the document every time the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of a linefeed. In order to recognize the new paragraph character in LibreOffice Writer the Alternative Find & Replace for Writer LibreOffice extension must be installed. A new paragraph character is denoted by the `\p` regular expression in Alternative Find & Replace.